# Shannon Entropy of Individual PE sections

Tags: malware

Why is Shannon Entropy of individual sections always between 0-8. Also why we need to create a 256 freq array while calculating the Shannon Entropy?

Comment: The mathematical answer is here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/95261/why-am-i-getting-information-entropy-greater-than-1

Comment: An intuitive answer is here, which also answers your question about the frequency array (hint: each byte represents one of 256 discrete states): https://towardsdatascience.com/the-intuition-behind-shannons-entropy-e74820fe9800

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The channel capacity of a single byte samples has a maximum of 8 bits.

Another way of thinking about it: If a single byte has the same value for every sample, you need 0 additional bits of information to describe the values.

If a single byte takes on 256 different values, [0 to 255], then for every sample you will need 8 additional bits of information to uniquely describe the values.

For example, if you were measuring the Shannon Entropy of a collection of Short values (2 bytes / 16 bits) it would range from 0 (constant) to 16 (completely random).